# replace HTML list with List added with JS

Tags: javascript, html

my solution: https://jsfiddle.net/thecodesalim/dsvgdkks/2/

HTML:

```
<div id=leaderboard class="panel hidden">
  <h1>Leaderboard</h1>
  <ol id=top10>
    <li>Jyn Erso</li>
    <li>Mon Mothma</li>
    <li class="me">Han Solo</li>
    <li>Galen Erso</li>
    <li>Thane Kyrell</li>
    <li>Norra Wexley</li>
    <li>Ciena Ree</li>
    <li>Malakili</li>
    <li>R5-D4</li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function updateLeaderBoard(arr,me){
    let players = document.getElementById("top10");
    for(let i =0; i < arr.length;i++){
        let li = document.createElement("li");
        li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(arr[i]));
        players.append(li);
        if(arr[i].includes(me)) li.classList.add("me");   
   }
}
updateLeaderBoard(["Jack","Robo","Simi"],"Robo");
```

I want the text content to be only the list in javascript, the html list should be replaced.
Thanks

Comment: edit : https://jsfiddle.net/thecodesalim/dsvgdkks/9/

Comment: Edit the question, don't post edits in comments.

Comment: I don't understand the question. What do you mean by "only accept li's from the js"?

Comment: Give the LIs from the JS a different class than the LIs from the HTML. Then your loop can test the class of the LI to tell if it came from the JS or HTML.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. Please [edit] the question to explain what you are trying to achieve, and which part of that you are having trouble with, and also please show the relevant HTML directly in the question body. *"the li's from the html should no be added"* - Added to what?

Comment: @Barmar  updated the question, thanks

Comment: @nnnnnn updated the question, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are saying that the HTML list is a placeholder and you want to clear it out and just insert whatever you want from js? If so, just empty the `<ol>` when you have selected it:

```
let players = document.getElementById("top10");
players.innerHTML = "";
```